# Passing Type to Method for Use in Generic

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I'm trying to understand why the following code does not work and how I need to change it to make it work. In short, I'm trying to pass a Type into the method and then use that Type when declaring List.

```
public void TestMethod(Type type)
{
    List<type> items = new List<type>();
}
```

I get the error: "'type' is a variable but is used like a type"

Thanks!

Comment: When you're *consuming* generics, you need to know what types you want to use as type parameters at *your* compile time. `type` is a type that you won't know until *runtime*.

Comment: If you know the type at compile time, change your method to: `public void TestMethod<T>() { List<T> items = new List<T>(); }` If you don't know the type at compile time, you can create the list using reflection.

Comment: An instance of the type `Type` is an object that describes a type.  If you have a typename (like, say `System.String`), then you can get a corresponding `Type` instance by saying `typeof(System.String)`, using the typename as a literal.  When you create an instance of a generic type (like `List<T>`), you need the literal type name (for example `List<System.String>`.  If you want to create a list of something based on a type instance you pass into a function, you'll need to use Reflection

Comment: There *is* a way to convert from `Type` to generics, but it is pretty ugly and involves runtime reflection (`MakeGenericType`/`MakeGenericMethod`). If it is even remotely possible, *stop now* (meaning: use an alternative solution) - it gets ugly pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this better.

Answer (score 3):

That would be:

```
public void TestMethod<T>()
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();
}
```

And as to the theory, the guys in the comments explained it pretty nicely. You can always check a documentation on generics :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without reflection. However, you can do it with reflection.

```
string typeName = "System.String";
Type typeArg = Type.GetType(typeName);

Type genericClass = typeof(List<>);
Type newClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeArg);

object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass);
```

Comment: The real trick, at this point, is that the only thing you can say about the `created` variable (in the general case) is that it is an object.  You can't cast it to anything useful.  In this particular case, you can cast it to a non-generic `IList` which makes it somewhat useful.  The is the _"ugly pretty quickly"_ path that @MarcGravell was referring to